# Disagreement over Discrete Math Property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, graph-theory, predicate-logic

I know I'm probably wrong, maybe someone can explain it to me. I'm doing practice problems in preparation for a test that is coming up.

> 12. Let u and v be two vertices in a graph G. Show that if G has two simple  paths between vertices u and v, then G has a simple circuit.
>
> Sol: Assume that G has the following two simple paths: (u,..P1..,v)
>   and (v,..P2..,u). Therefore, G has the circuit (u,..P1..,v,..P2..,u).
>   If this circuit has no  repeated edges, then the proof is complete.
>
> **Otherwise, let (x,y) be the first  edge that occurs in P1 and is repeated in P2. In this case, the circuit can be  represented as
>   follows: (u,..P1..,x,y,..P1..,v,..P2..,y,x,..P2..,u) This circuit can
>   be reduced to become as follows: (u,..P1..,x,..P2..,u) where no edge
>   in P1 is repeated in P2(because edge (x,y) was the first edge in  P1
>   that is repeated in P2). Thus, the reduced circuit is simple.**

I've marked the part I'm having trouble with in bold. I don't
understand how we can just strip out the y vertex and simplify the
graph. I suspect I'm not preparing the graph properly, but I've
uploaded an example image to show why the graph can't be simplified.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete the edge that goes from $x$ to $y$, you get a simple circuit going from $u$ to $x$ and then back from $x$ to $u$ along a different path, and that's a simple circuit.  It never goes to $y$, nor to $v$.  The problem is only to show that there is at least one simple circuit.  It's not required to include any particular vertices, such as $y$ and $v$.